Sending different stomp message types to the same queue
I'm writing a Spring Boot application (App) which handles STOMP messages sent from a web browser (or Agent). The messages (Commands) arrive, are repackaged and published to a topic which a second Spring Boot application (Agent) is subscribed to.
There are several different types of Command with different associated data and I'm wondering if there is a generally accepted pattern to handle this.
Most of the Spring examples are just sending Greeting strings or a single type.
StompSessionHandler.getPayloadType(StompHeaders) lets one read the header and determine what kind of type the payload will be serialised into and given to StompSessionHandler.handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload).
So is there a standard way of communicating through the headers what type of message is contained in the payload? Do I just invent my own header key and use that? Do people just use key/value pairs (or maps) to transmit variable message payloads (I don't like this idea because I feel like Jackson2 should be doing most of the type conversions for me)? Is there any documentation or case studies I can read? Or do people just have a different topic endpoint per message type. Any advice on strategy would be appreciated.
